# Keep timestamp information when using daily groupby

Tags: pandas

Please see code example and output below.  Using `groupby` I am able to identify the max `"Ask Volume Bid Volume Total"`value for each day.

I also want to see what time of day this happened for each day. Basically I don't want to lose the time from the timestamp.  How do I do this please?

[image: df_view]

Comment: You could do `data.loc[grouped['Ask Volume Bid Volumne Total'].idxmax()]`

Comment: Great, thanks Ed.  I will accept if you post as an answer.

Comment: For future reference, please post text and not images of your code, one should provide that as a minimum as code can't be reproduced as easily from text, additionally you should also provide raw data, code to reproduce the df, your attempts and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax) on the `groupby` object to index back into your original df so you can see the full resolution timestamps associated with those max values:

```
data.loc[grouped['Ask Volume Bid Volumne Total'].idxmax()]
```